# Where complicated template logic should reside in MVC framwork?

Tags: django, model-view-controller

I am wondering where complicated template logic should reside when using MVC framework like Django.

For example, I want to display the list of some models with their children's children's children's models grouping by their category.

Grouping some model's children's children's children's model is only for displaying purpose.

Embedding this logic is too complicated to implement in Template.

However, I think model shouldn't care about how it would be displayed, and controller is not for the place for reusable logic.

If I could create middleware between template and controller, that seems right choice, but I can't do that.

Where should complicated logic for template resides?

Comment: You can usually contain complex logic within your `models.py`, and keep your views and templates as simple as possible.

Comment: To answer your example scenario, you should use [django-mptt](https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)!  It will make your life much easier when dealing with nested structures.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when my `TemplateView` has some complicated data to display, I calculate it and pass it to template by overriding `get_context_data`

```py
class MyView(TemplateView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['childrens_children...'] = ...
        return context
```